# Grails Criteria Projections - Distinct Projection by two properties

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

I want to get all possible combinations of two columns using Grails Criteria Projections.

I try this:

```
def criteria = {
   projections{
        property('colA')
        property('colB')
   }
}

def allCombinations = MyDomainEntity.createCriteria().list(criteria)
```

But, that code returns all the repeated combinations of colA and colB.

I also tried to use `distinct`, but only works for a single column.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I just want to fetch the count of such combinations. Any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of the real problem you try to solve, but according to what you've said you should use `groupProperty`.

Here is the example:

```
// Your domain class
class TestEntity {
   String field1
   String field2
}

// test distinct projection
class TestEntityTest extends GroovyTestCase {

    void testDistinctByTwoColumns() {
        new TestEntity(field1: 'test1', field2: 'test2').save()
        new TestEntity(field1: 'test1', field2: 'test2').save() // duplicate
        new TestEntity(field1: 'test1', field2: 'test2').save() // duplicate
        new TestEntity(field1: 'test3', field2: 'test4').save()
        final result = TestEntity.withCriteria {
            projections {
                groupProperty('field1')
                groupProperty('field2')
            }
        }
        assertEquals(2, result.size())
    }
}
```

P.S. I use Grails 2.5.5 for testing. Maybe your version is a little bit different, but I hope the idea is clear.